# Can't get OMXPlayer to display video

Tags: pi-3, omxplayer, raspivid

I am watching a tutorial on YouTube and literally following everything that he is doing....

I have recorded a video and now trying to play it using the omxplayer

When i go to play my video using the command "omxplayer videotest.h264" that I recorded, It's not showing up for me but i am getting the same message (Some messages about width, height etc and have a nice day) as the guy on the video.

I have installed the omxplayer already using the "sudo apt-get install omxplayer"

I don't know how to display the video that I have recorded. All help is appreciated. Thank You very much!

.....And yes, I am a noobie to all this lol

I typed in the code...

```
omxplayer videotest.h264
```

The result is what I got below but I couldn't see the video being played

```
Video codec omx-h264 width 640 height 480 profile 100 fps 25.000000
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
V:PortSettingsChanged: 640x480@25.00 interlace:0 deinterlace:0 anaglyph:0 par:1.00 display:0 layer:0 alpha:255 aspectMode:0
have a nice day ;)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74734/discussion-on-question-by-alex-cant-get-omxplayer-to-display-video).

Answer (score 0):

Some debugging Questions and suggestions:

Check your movie file.  What's its length (`ls -l videotest.h64`)? Have you viewed this movie on another device/computer? I.e. to ensure good encoding, etc.

Are you running `omxplayer` from a GUI, or from just a terminal command line, and NOT via a ssh session?  Your print-out shows `display:0`.

Per the omxplayer documentation, check the output device: `omxplayer --display n`.
`n` is 5 for HDMI and 4 for the official 7" touchscreen.

Perhaps try another video player from the GUI, such as VLC media player.

Comment: You can run _omxplayer_ from SSH session. The video will be displayed on **display:0** by default.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're using a 32-bit or 64-bit OS.

`omxplayer` uses openmax, which isn't supported by 64-bit kernels.