# Play 2 videos on 2 hdmi displays with rpi 4

Tags: omxplayer, pi-4

New raspberry has 2 hdmi connectors.

Is it possible to play 2 different videos at the same time (one per screen)  with a single raspberry ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can with `omxplayer` in terminal.

```
# run the first video in the background with key inputs disabled
omxplayer --no-keys --display=2 --loop /home/pi/first.mp4 &

# run the second video normally
omxplayer --display=7 --loop /home/pi/second.mp4
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is two different HDMI ports.

Comment: Thanks but how, i have tried --display 1 or --display 2 argument and it plays on hdmi 1 each time

Comment: Well that's another question. Perhaps you should put more info into the question.

Comment: Have a look at: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81526/cant-get-omxplayer-to-display-video

Comment: no it is the same question ! I have read this post before. I have tried 4 and 5 value. It is always the first hdmi

Comment: Haver you tried to add the environment variable for the DISPLAY like: `DISPLAY=:0 omxplayer.....` ?

Comment: Yes. As i told you i have already read this post

Comment: the linked question refers to a pi 3 not a pi 4, so is meaningless - and while the answer technically answers the question, it's of poorer quality than the question. Clearly the OP wants to know HOW

Comment: also., nothing in any omxplayer docs / help tellsyou how to target a particular HDMI output on the pi 4, not as far as I can see, and there's been no commits to the omxplayer repo regarding such options